# Отображается разное значение объекта в свернутом и развернутом виде в консоли разработчика Chrome и FireFox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, отладка, консоль, firefox

Очень странная проблема. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем она заключается.
Обратите внимание на свойство "status".
В свернутом виде - он 8889, а при разворачивании - 42.
Что в Chrome, что в Firefox - ситуация одинаковая.

[image: Пример проблемы]

Comment: Может быть это не `status` 42, а 42 свойства всего у объекта?

Comment: При разворачивании,  консоль отображает текущее состояние объекта, а не то, которое было на момент вывода

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
 status: 3000,
 path: "/alt/src"
}

console.log(obj); // {status: 3000, path: "/alt/src"}
obj.status = 4000;
```

Скорее всего объект изменяется после вызова `console.log()`? Проверьте.

Answer (score 0):

Через JSON:

> console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, стоит изложить, каким именно образом написанное вами отвечает на вопрос.